# EF with Oracle in Visual Studio error message?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, visual-studio

I'm helping a colleague to get his Visual Studio 2013 set up so that he can use EF with Oracle. We are getting an error message "Your project references the latest version of Entity Framework; however, an Entity Framework database provider compatible with this version could not be found". We used NuGet to install the Oracle.Managed driver first and the Oracle.Manged.EntityFramework. When we look at the properties of Oracle.Manged driver int he project the runtime version is "v4.0.30319".

We are able to connect to Oracle using the TNSname with LinqPad and TOAD.

I'm able to get EF with Oracle to work in my VS 2013 following the same steps so I know it should be able to work. I just don't know what to check on his machine to find out what the difference between our machines are.

I'm looking for any suggestions on what I can look at.

Comment: Can you post also the contents of your packages.config please?

Comment: I will as soon as we can. We are installing ODAC v12c Release 3 at the moment to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

We are using this config (packages.config):

```
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" version="12.1.022" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework" version="12.1.022" targetFramework="net45" />
```

and it is working. To download version specific nuget:

```
Install-Package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess -Version 12.1.022
```

EntityFramework 6.1.3 is the latest now and this version of the Oracle driver can work with it.

Comment: Thanks, we will look at this as well and post back the results.